# Jboss connectivity with MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, rhel6

Need help for `JBoss` integration with `MySQL` DB. 

`The`WAR`file is copied to`Jboss deployment` directory .

`$ ls /MRTSTP/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/
   README.txt  RT.war  RT.war.deployed`

DB is restored and necessary permissions granted for db user to access data from DB . The issue for me is where to add necessary DB related configuration like `JNDI` ,  username and password in `JBOSS`so that application can connect to the database.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1):

you could add a db resource pool file to save your connection.
and then use the JNDI to look up above resource pool. example as below for MSSQL.

```
 <jndi-name>MSSQLDS</jndi-name>
```